# IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait(), using synchronized static method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception

I have already read about this question but my case I think is different:
[IllegalMonitorStateException on wait() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call)

I'm using java on Android studio.
The error I get it is the following:

```
MiniatureAnnotations: Problem annotating via GMS.
    java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
        at jaw.a(PG:20)
        at hnt.b(PG:115)
        at com.google.android.apps.messaging.shared.datamodel.action.GenericWorkerQueueAction.b(PG:81)
        at eqs.run(PG:1)
        at yya.run(PG:3)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at yws.run(PG:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I'm not using a lock on an object but synchronized the method. Such as:

```
public synchronized static boolean send(Repository repository, Context context) {
   //  code... [I do not use wait or notify]
}
```

or:

```
 public static synchronized void checkWorkers(Context context) {
        WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
        ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> senderWorker = workManager.getWorkInfosByTag(tagSenderWorker);
        if (senderWorker.isCancelled()) {
            PeriodicSmsWorker.initializePeriodicSmsWorker(context, REPLACE_POLICY);
            updateCheckSenderWorker();
    } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - LAST_CHECK_SENDER_WORKER > MAX_TIME_WORKER_INACTIVE) {
        updateCheckSenderWorker();
        PeriodicSmsWorker.initializePeriodicSmsWorker(context, REPLACE_POLICY);
    }
}
```

Why am I getting IllegalMonitorStateException if I do not use wait or notify?

Edit1: disable Dexguard based on: 
[How to disable Dexguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508560/how-to-disable-dexguard)

in gradle app:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            minifyEnabled rootProject.ext.enableDexGuardPlugin
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
dependencies {
    ...
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    if(rootProject.ext.enableDexGuardPlugin) {
        apply plugin: 'dexguard'
    }
}
```

gradle project:

```
 ext {
        roomVersion = '2.2.0-beta01'
        archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0-alpha03'
        coreTestingVersion = "2.1.0-rc01"
        enableDexGuardPlugin = false
    }
```

However I have the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The offensive invocation of `wait()` is made from the method `jaw.a`. If you cannot find its real name, then disable DexGuard, rebuild and run your application again. The stack trace should show the exact place where `wait()` without `synchronized` is invoked.

Comment: I tried to disable DexGuard but I still get the same error.

Comment: of course it should raise the same error, please show what stack trace it prints now.